# upgrade to PostgreSQL 12 in cluster

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have two node PostgreSQL 11 HA setup as follows.

node1 - hamaster.myorg.net

node2 - haslave.myorg.net

`recovery.conf` on node2 is as follows:

```
standby_mode          = 'on'
primary_conninfo      = 'host=hamaster.myorg.net port=5432 user=<user_here> password=<password_here> sslmode=require sslcompression=0'
trigger_file = '/tmp/MasterNow'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

I want to upgrade PostgreSQL to 12 on both the system. I have identified following steps in exact sequence:

1. Stop PostgreSQL on master node.
2. Update the RPM (i am using centos 7.8) to PostgreSQL 12 on master node and upgrade the PostgreSQL using `pg_upgrade`
3. Start the PostgreSQL on master node.
4. Stop the PostgreSQL on slave node.
5. Update the RPM (i am using centos 7.8) to PostgreSQL 12 on slave node and upgrade the PostgreSQL using `pg_upgrade`
6. On slave node, copy the contents from `recovery.conf` to `postgresql.conf` and remove the `recovery.conf`. Also create the file `standby.signal` in data directory on slave server. Rename `trigger_file` to `promote_trigger_file`. Remove the line `standby_mode          = 'on'` as this is NOT required by PostgreSQL 12.
7. Start the PostgreSQL on slave node.

Is there anything missing?

Comment: You should adapt `postgresql.conf` manually. Also, you'll have to run `pg_basebackup` to create a new standby, upgrading won't work.

Comment: [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html#PGUPGRADE-STEP-REPLICAS) explains the different options you have to upgrade the standby

Comment: Running `pg_basebackup` again is like creating the cluster again. This is painful if having large amount of data. Will upgrade NOT work at all ? @Laurenz

Comment: Yes, this is painful, but it is the only way.

Comment: Ok thanks. Any chance to use `pg_rewind` instead of full `pg_basebackup`  for standby nodes upgrade?

Comment: [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html#PGUPGRADE-STEP-REPLICAS) explains ways other than using `pg_basebackup` for the standby

Comment: If `pg_basebackup` is too painful, you may also look into using `rsync` to minimize downtime, but it is a little riskier

Comment: I'd recommend to set up a new pg 12 cluster and dump data from old to new server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Any new way for upgrading PostgreSQL streaming replication cluster(2-3 node), without using `pg_basebackup` ?